# Does Participating in social network increase page rank?

Tags: search-engine, pagerank

HI,
 I would like to know whether particpating in social networking sites and placing my website link there increases backlink.

And also does search engine crawl those links.

Please provide me suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they add the `nofollow` attribute to the outgoing links, it won't bring you any benefits.

Like this:

```
<a href="http://www.myspansite.com" rel="nofollow" />
```

Check out the source code of similar pages of other people to find out if they put this command in the links or not.

P.S. Comments in blogs are almost all nofollowed these days.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to nofollow, also if the posted link is not public then SE crawler won't find that.